# Single Custom Seekbar in Android with different range

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have tried many solution to achieve a single custom seekbar with different range
when reaches to certain points. I am working on science project where i need a custom seekbar for android application. where the seekbar will have 1st range from
0-50 with Red color background, 2nd range from 51-67 with Yellow color background and Last 68-100 with Green color background. All the 3 ranges should be of equal size or equally divided. I have tried a lot and able to set equal size background of custom seekbar in android with the help of this tutorial:
[https://azzits.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/customseekbar/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuZj8.png)

The problem is setting different range and increment values based on criteria.

I have also attached image drawn in paint to get a clear idea about what i want to achieve.

How to achieve this. Please help.
[Custom Seek Bar with different range and background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuZj8.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `SeekBar`'s change listener and apply arithmetic operations to get specific values. For example, first half mapped to 0-4 and second to 5-100:

```
if (value < 50){
    value /= 10;
} else {
    value = (int)(5 + (  value - 50 ) * ( 95 / 50f ));
}
```

You can increase range to avoid resolution decrease on upscale, and, similarly, parametrize it with array of range sizes. No custom classes required.